# Ef Core static extension queries

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, static

Unit of Work/Repositories are not really best practice.

They're known for hiding EF Core and not perform very well.

I have some goals I want to achieve:

1. store queries (so i don"t have to rewrite them each time)
2. easy access

I thought about using static extension methods to provide queries like this:

```
UserEntity.GetUserById(int userId, _dbContext)

public static GetUserById(int userId, _dbContext) => 
_dbContext.Set<UserEntity>().where(x=> x.userId == userId)
```

I know its not recommended to use static. But I don't see any problems using it for stateless queries. And I would have them bundled directly to the entity, so they"re easy to find.

Q1 : Will I incur problems when I store a lot of queries in static extension methods?

Q2 : Is there a better pattern then Unit of Work / Repository?

Storing the queries in the entities itself is not an option for me because I share the entities with a Blazor project.

Comment: You should read [Wikipedia's article on Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).  Pay special attention to the second paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unit of Work / Repositories are not really best practice.

Sort of.  The DbContext is already both a Repository and a Unit-of-Work implementation.  What's controversial is adding an additional UoW or Repository later on top of your DbContext implementation.

And instance methods/properties on your DbContext are the canonical place to put queries that will be used in multiple locations.

And note that [`DbSet<T>.Find(object[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.find) is an out-of-the-box key lookup API with cache-readthrough semantics.

Comment: And it is mostly also disputed because i have never seen one that is not breaking the repository when it gets to things like upodating multiple unit of work in one transaction or going to another repoository to get related objects. Most are very badly implemented.

Comment: Absolutely.  Low reward, high risk.